# Calling Transfer event causes infinite gas estimation solc

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, solc

solc estimates an infinite gas usage from `_transfer` and I am unsure why. I did find that if I comment out the `Transfer(_from, _to, _amount)` line, the gas usage becomes finite.

Here is the minimum code to reproduce the issue:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Token {

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);

    struct Balance {
        uint amount;
        uint lastUpdated;
    }

    mapping (address => Balance) public balances;


    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _amount) internal returns (bool success) {

            // check if sender has sufficient balance
            require(balances[_from].amount >= _amount);
            //check for uint overflow
            require(balances[_to].amount + _amount > balances[_to].amount);

            balances[_from].amount -= _amount;
            balances[_to].amount += _amount;

            Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Using solc version `0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.Darwin.appleclang`

Comment: did you ever find the answer?

Comment: no, but it ended up not being an issue—I was able to publish the contract regardless

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this problem with Zeppelin BasicToken contract. The answer I have found is that SAfeMath operations cannot be analyzed statically so safe math causes this error.

```
 function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
assert(b <= a);
return a - b;
```

}

/**
  * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }

Might be that you are getting it due to this check

```
    require(balances[_to].amount + _amount > balances[_to].amount);
```

However, I don't know how this problem can be solved without removing all overflow checks. Execution is not a problem, just static analysis and .estimageGas() calls in Web3.

Comment: so it's not possible to estimate gas for transactions that involve a transfer?

Comment: it is possible to estimate gas in most cases dynamically, but it might be impossible to do that statically at the time of compilation - this is what is all about. So you get warnings about potential infinite gas consumption at the time of compilation

Comment: If you're using `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;`, apparently the compiler now handles safe math internally.