# Transfer event Vs. transfer and send

Tags: solidity

In this contract - [Contract with Transfer event](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34775/calling-transfer-event-causes-infinite-gas-estimation-solc); it is using `Transfer` event.

But as per my understanding, [events](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events) are for logging and as a means to trigger call back to front end javascript only, not to do transactions.

How does this `Transfer` event become equivalent to `msg.sender.transfer()` API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msg.sender.transfer()` is used to transfer ether only. It's not needed for tokens. Token balances are kept in the Token smart contract, transferring tokens is simply updating the mapping values inside the smart contract.